# ISO 9797-1 MAC algorithm 3 and padding method 1 example in Java?

Tags: java, cryptography

Looking through Java Cryptography Architecture and some code examples, I have learned how to calculate Mac using Mac class:

Please find the below code to calculate MAC:

```
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
mac.init(<secretKeyHere>);
byte[] macHash = mac.doFinal(<encryptedTextHere>);
```

But actually  I am looking for a way to calculate Mac using the ISO 9797-1 Algorithm 3(Retail MAC) and padding 1 (if necessary, add bits with value 0 to the end of the data until the padded data is a multiple of n, where n is the block size of the DES cipher, i.e. 8).

Can anyone please suggest code example in java?

Comment: Do you have a test vector (key, input value) in hexadecimals or base 64? If so please add it to your question.

Comment: key is 64 byte key and output required is 35 bytes (70 characters) Alphanumerical data. Can you please help me on this. Thanks @Maarten Bodewes

Answer (score 1):

[BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) includes a [ready-to-use class](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/crypto/macs/ISO9797Alg3Mac.html) to calculate "Retail MAC".

Usage [example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.bouncycastle.crypto.macs.ISO9797Alg3Mac):

```
public byte[] getRetailMAC(byte[] key, byte[] data) {
    BlockCipher cipher = new DESEngine();
    Mac mac = new ISO9797Alg3Mac(cipher, 64, new ISO7816d4Padding());

    KeyParameter keyP = new KeyParameter(key);
    mac.init(keyP);
    mac.update(data, 0, data.length);

    byte[] out = new byte[8];

    mac.doFinal(out, 0);

    return out;
}
```

---

To use *optional* zero padding you need to perform your padding yourself as Bouncy Castle does *always* pad, even when performing the ill-defined zero padding.

```
public byte[] getRetailMAC(byte[] key, byte[] data) {
    int macSizeBits = 64;

    BlockCipher cipher = new DESEngine();

    Mac mac = new ISO9797Alg3Mac(cipher, macSizeBits);

    KeyParameter keyP = new KeyParameter(key);
    mac.init(keyP);
    mac.update(data, 0, data.length);

    // perform padding manually - NOT REQUIRED, SEE UPDATE
    int n = cipher.getBlockSize();
    int zeroPaddingRequired = n - (data.length + n - 1) % n - 1; 
    for (int i = 0; i < zeroPaddingRequired; i++) {
        mac.update((byte) 0x00);
    }

    byte[] out = new byte[macSizeBits / Byte.SIZE];
    mac.doFinal(out, 0);

    return out;
}
```

Note that this kind of padding does not distinguish between messages that end with one or more zero valued bytes (and if the number of blocks of 8 bytes remains the same). For that reason it is not secure for messages where only the number of bytes is pre-defined.

**UPDATE**:

The manual padding is unnecessary because this padding mode (type 1 in the spec) is actually the default and performed *within the MAC implementation*. So you would get this when not supplying *any* padding. Note that this is *not* the same as supplying `ZeroBytePadding` because the last one *always* pads.

Comment: Is this `ISO7816d4Padding` padding 1.. please confirm so that i will try to use this and will confirm if its works..thanks @mnistic

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Padding 1", what is that?

Comment: Padding method 1:
If necessary, add bits with value 0 to the end of the data until the padded data is a multiple of n. (If the original data was already a multiple of n, no bits are added.)..I need this as well. Thanks @mnistic

Comment: OK, I believe that's `ZeroBytePadding`, so just try using that instead of `ISO7816d4Padding`.

Comment: Probably .. but i couldn't find the Padding method 1 class same like as ISO7816d4Padding. Can you please help me on this. Thanks.@mnistic

Comment: Just do `Mac mac = new ISO9797Alg3Mac(cipher, 64, new ZeroBytePadding());`

Comment: so is this "ZeroBytePadding" means padding method 1. please confirm.. and also 
 how we can decrypt the same again using mac algorithm 3 and padding method 1. thanks@mnistic

Comment: Sounds like it to me... You don't use MAC to decrypt, but to verify integrity.

Comment: Okay.. is out - byte[] out = new byte[8]; can be changed to 16 or 32 or 64 bytes..is it possible as i tried by giving 16 but looks like not working so..thanks @mnistic

Comment: @Chassu I've added some code to the sample of mnistic, let me know if it works.

Comment: key is 64 byte key and output required is 35 bytes (70 characters) Alphanumerical data. Can you please help me on this. Thanks @Maarten Bodewes

Comment: Hi @Maarten Bodewes, please help on this as key is 64 byte key and output required is 35 bytes (70 characters) Alphanumerical data.

Comment: Please ask separate questions and make clear what the requirements are. 64 byte key doesn't make any sense to me, and generally the output format should be specified, not just the length. Your comments don't make any sense to me.